# How to get value out of this...?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Can someone explain me how to get data out of this...like if I just want subject, description..etc...

```
stdClass Object
(
    [tickets] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [url] => https://codemymobilecom.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/1.json
                    [id] => 1
                    [external_id] => 
                    [via] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [channel] => sample_ticket
                            [source] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [from] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [to] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [rel] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [created_at] => 2015-04-22T08:30:29Z
                    [updated_at] => 2015-05-19T06:01:22Z
                    [type] => incident
                    [subject] => This is a sample ticket requested and submitted by you
                    [raw_subject] => This is a sample ticket requested and submitted by you
                    [description] => This is the first comment. Feel free to delete this sample ticket.
                    [priority] => high
                    [status] => closed
                    [recipient] => 
                    [requester_id] => 794599791
                    [submitter_id] => 794599791
                    [assignee_id] => 794599791
                    [organization_id] => 39742491
                    [group_id] => 24344491
                    [collaborator_ids] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [forum_topic_id] => 
                    [problem_id] => 
                    [has_incidents] => 
                    [due_at] => 
                    [tags] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => sample
                            [1] => zendesk
                        )

                    [custom_fields] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [satisfaction_rating] => 
                    [sharing_agreement_ids] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [followup_ids] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [brand_id] => 565681
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [url] => https://codemymobilecom.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/10.json
                    [id] => 10 //multiple object like [0]...
```

Thanks...Any help would be great..

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried foreach...but no success...

Comment: Post your attempts. Along with expected output

Comment: I am not seeing any code with `foreach` in the question.

Comment: I didn't add that...as it wasn't working..

Comment: try this, $object->toArray();

Comment: Even if you haven't achieved what you hoped, it is useful to post the code you have attempted, so that we can see how far you got, and give you specific tips on where you went wrong. It also helps show that you have put in some effort, rather than expecting people to do all the work for you. See more in the [ask] help page.

Comment: Don't just keep it in mind. Click [edit] and improve this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you need to access to array's key, use `[]`. When you have object, use `->`.

```
echo $obj->tickets[0]->subject; // returns first subject
echo $obj->tickets[0]->description; // returns first description
```

You can put it into `foreach` loop, of course to gain all subjects, etc.

Comment: @MoidMohd: I think php.net should be the source where you find everything.

Answer (score 1):

It's STD object so use properties

```
$obj->tickets[0]->subject
$obj->tickets[0]->description
```

You can obviously loop tickets

```
foreach($obj->tickets as $ticket)
{
   echo $ticket->subject;
   echo $ticket->description
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is an std object.to get subject and description follow this

```
$obj->tickets[0]->subject;
$obj->tickets[0]->description;
```

if you feel better in array just make it array using this code

```
$array = get_object_vars($obj);
```